# Database for countries , state , city

Tags: sql, asp.net-core-mvc

I want to create a cascading dropdownlist for address (country , state , city). From where can I get the database for these. I did search around the net , but I couldn't find one. I am not looking for paid service as this is a learning website.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I couldn't find any databases for this, which I wasn't overly shocked by (most people don't leave around databases connectable by just anyone). I looked instead for xml / json sources that you could pull from each time or as a single download and convert it to your own db.

https://awesomeopensource.com/project/dr5hn/countries-states-cities-database

Comment: Great resources, but last updated 8 years ago.